# Joining data from multiple tables using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables in my database:

```
Links
-----------------------
id | student| class
1 | 2 | 1
2 | 1 | 1
3 | 1 | 2

Student
-----------------------
id | name | age
1 | Bob | 16
2 | Jane | 17

Class
_______________________
id | subject
1 | Math
2 | Science
```

I want to be able to look at the links table to see what students are in what class and return the results from the student table per class. So, if I were looking at a page that had class information I would get all the students information that are in that class. I want to be able to use Sqlalchemy to make this query, which is what's confusing me since I can't just a straight up JOIN or something.

I'll be passing the class information to the function in Flask, like:

```
@main.route('/class/<class_id>')
@login_required
def view_class(class_id):
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why cant you use join ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use JOIN statements in SQLAlchemy

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below and since class keyword is reserved in python, you need to use a different column name for Links Table and i have used it below as student_class

```
@main.route('/class/<class_id>')
@login_required
def view_class(class_id):

    output = session.query(Student).join(Link, Student.id == Link.student).join(Class, Link.student_class == Class.id).filter(Class.id == class_id).all()
```

Comment: That works, however, I think I'm doing something different, as I don't use the session to query, I use something like:

`Students.query.filter_by(is_enrolled='True')`

instead of

`session.query(Students).filter_by...`

When I tried doing Student.query.join instead of session.query(Student) it returns a list [<Students 1>] and I'm not sure how to interact with that to get the details